# How to programatically invoke a method which sets source of *ngFor and render corresponding html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm working on Angular project.

When users clicks on a categories I need to show corresponding subcategories.

For example by clicking on **Drinks** I need to display: **Coke**, **Fanta**, **Pepsi**...

By clicking on Food for example I need to display: **Burgers**, **Potatoes**, **Fish**

And this works when I'm clicking on main groups, subgroups are changing and displaying as expected.

But I would like to set Drinks as Default category, so when I come to a screen I want to see **Drinks** and Coke, **Fanta**, **Pepsi**.. Like I've manually pressed on Drinks..

I've tried to achieve this on next way:

***step 1:***

Get data from a database, all main categories, all subcategories, so I might apply filter - based on categoryId - get all subcategories:

```
export class MainScreenCategories implements OnInit {

  @Input() groups: Group[];
  @Input() subGroups: Group[];
  filteredSubGroups: Group[];
  selectedId: string;
  selectedSubId: string;

  constructor(
  private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef, 
  private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
  private _groupService: GroupService, 
  private _http: HttpClient,
  private _articleService: ArticleService,
  private _globalHelper: GlobalHelperService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedId = '78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53';
    this.groups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['groups'];
    this.subGroups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['subGroups'];

    // This is source to my template directive *ngFor - filteredSubGroups
    this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId == this.selectedId);
    console.log(this.filteredSubGroups);

    //this._ref.detectChanges();

    //I've tried adding timeout while fetching data
    //this._groupService.getAll().subscribe(data => setTimeout(() => this.groups = data, 0));
    //this._groupService.getAllSubGroups().subscribe(data => setTimeout(() => this.subGroups = data, 0));

  }
```

***step 2:***

Write some HTML to display data:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="whatever">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let subgroup of filteredSubGroups">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="" data-target="" class="btn categories-btn">
                {{subgroup.title | uppercase}}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see guys I'm looping `filteredSubGroups` to display subcategories.

And my `console.log(filteredSubGroups)` in `ngOnInit` contains right data also,, but when I run app first time I get this message in my console:

[image]

When I clear console and go to another component's template, and back to this one, I can see in my console there is no errors anymore just 3 subcategories logged there because I said in `ngOnInit` `console.log(filteredSubGroups)`,

[image]

but even if they are logged, they are not visible in html template, and that's biggest problem, I can not figure out why?

Thanks guys

Any kind of help is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should subscribe to the Activated Route data.
Using something like this.

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
    if(data){
      const {groups, subGroups} = data;
      this.groups = groups;
      this.subGroups = subGroups;
      this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId == this.selectedId);
    }

})
```

What is probably happening is that the first call to the route kills the component because of the null. Then clicking around reinitializes the component after the data has time to asynchronously be fetched .

Comment: Can you edit my example to show me exactlly what to edit

Comment: I've tried few things, but that did not work for me unfortunatelly :(